# Devise on Rails 3: How to override the message a user already signed in gets when trying to sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

The situation is the following, using Devise and Rails 3

- A user sign up
- After successfully submitting the signup form, Devise logs her in, redirects (to the home page in my case) and shows a custom message (in application_controller.rb)

  ```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)

    flash[:notice] = "Hi " + current_user.username + " , you're now signed in."

    super

  end
  ```
- The user tries then to sign up again. In this case the sigup form is not displayed, the user is redirected to the homepage and the same message is displayed.

How do I set up different messages in the two cases above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the followings:

- This behaviour is caused by the registration controller, which has a prepend_before_filter that triggers a call to require_no_authentication. Require_no_authentication simply redirects to root_url if the user is logged in
- There is an open ticket on github, since it's quite difficult to override the method (see here: [Devise issues](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/labels/Feature?authenticity_token=8d1ea346204cc488af2738cc236f8084c4b5e36d#issue/729)
- Nevertheless, as pointed out  by Jose' Valim on the same page, it doesn't make much sense to show to a logged in user the sign up link... I'll modify the interface of my application to hide the signup link if the user is logged in.